# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaFileProvider <- $cordovaFile <- DashCtrl

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

Created a test project to try [$cordovaFile](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) from ngCordova, But after *injecting* $cordovaFile to one of the controllers and running xcode project, I see Unknown provider error.

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$cordovaFile) {})
```

***I really don't see a way for this error to pop-up.***

## Explained the commands what I ran on terminal below:

Created a new project using:

```
1. ionic start writefile
2. platform ios is added by default (using mac)
3. cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file - added file plugin using ngcordova source
4. ionic build ios
5. Ran the project using xcode to run on simulator.
```

Debugging the issue, but posting on community which might help me in solving quicker.

Comment: Did you include `ngCordova` module? `angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])`

Comment: refer: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/use-cordovafile-in-ionic-application/14249/9

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First install the plugin using

```
bower install -SF ngCordova
```

Include `ng-cordova.js` from `dist` directory from the included `ngCordova` library, in your `index.html`

Then include 'ngCordova' in your app

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])
```

Comment: anyways, might be helpful for others who fall into same problem.. :)